# Assert private inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I would like to assert that a base class is only inherited private.

```
class Base {
  static_assert(...); //check if its derived privat

};

class PublicDerived : public Base {}; //this should fail
class PrivateDerived : private Base {}; //this should work
```

Is there a way to achieve this? 
Base can also be a template class.

Comment: Combination of `is_base_of` and `is_convertible`? I suppose that could give a false negative if `PrivateDerived` provides a conversion operator, although that would be a strange design.

Comment: Real question is: WHY? Why do you need this feature? Looks like you are trying to overengineer something or you are trying solve some problem in strange way.

Comment: Could maybe be achieved with CRTP, but I concur that this doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2dac0c24bd084d0 Does this work? I mean it compiles for my case but I dont know if it does what you want. That said I'm also curious why you need this in the first place.

Comment: @Borgleader: I thought of that approach, but the the derived classes `PrivateDerived` have no access to the must-be-private base class at all.  Also, your "does not compile" comment needs some additional machinery using `friend class, right now it would compile.

Comment: @Borgleader I do not get it. What this link suppose to prove? It doesn't do what was requested. Compilation should fail on `Derived2`.

Comment: @MarekR the goal was something similar to boost::noncopyable. I've seen they solved it with a protected DTOR, so this should also work for me. I don't want that someone calls ~Base, because the DTOR isn't virtual.

Comment: @MarekR It doesnt matter because its already privately inherited, the private class is well private and the only class that can derive from it privately inherits it doesnt matter later down the chain

Comment: @BenVoigt not sure what you mean, if i uncomment the line i get a compilation error (is private within this context) and thats the point.

Comment: Ahh it's a class, I was thinking in terms of a namespace.  Ok fine, but you still have the problem that the derived classes cannot access their private base class, because it's hidden by the wrapper layer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I don't want that the destructor is called from this base class. For example from `delete Base*` or `unique_ptr<Base>`.
A protected destructor solves this issue.
Now the derived classes can use these functionalities the base class provides.

Public inheritation is still possible, but my use case is fullfilled.

```
class Base {
//...
protected:
  constexpr Base() noexcept = default;
  ~Base() noexcept = default;
};
```